# Remove all words in string containing punctuation (R)

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

How (in R) would I remove any word in a string containing punctuation, keeping words without?

```
  test.string <- "I am:% a test+ to& see if-* your# fun/ction works o\r not"

  desired <- "I a see works not"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach using `sub` which seems to work:

```
test.string <- "I am:% a test$ to& see if* your# fun/ction works o\r not"
gsub("[A-Za-z]*[^A-Za-z ]\\S*\\s*", "", test.string)

[1] "I a see works not"
```

This approach is to use the following regex pattern:

```
[A-Za-z]*     match a leading letter zero or more times
[^A-Za-z ]    then match a symbol once (not a space character or a letter)
\\S*          followed by any other non whitespace character
\\s*          followed by any amount of whitespace
```

Then, we just replace with empty string, to remove the words having one or more symbols in them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex

```
(?<=\\s|^)[a-z0-9]+(?=\\s|$)
```

- `(?<=\\s|^)` - positive lookbehind, match should be preceded by space or start of string.
- `[a-z0-9]+` - Match alphabets and digits one or more time,
- `(?=\\s|$)` - Match must be followed by space or end of string

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ScVHoL/2/)

Tim's edit:

This answer uses a whitelist approach, namely identify all words which the OP *does* want to retain in his output.  We can try matching using the regex pattern given above, and then connect the vector of matches using `paste`:

```
test.string <- "I am:% a test$ to& see if* your# fun/ction works o\\r not"
result <- regmatches(test.string,gregexpr("(?<=\\s|^)[A-Za-z0-9]+(?=\\s|$)",test.string, perl=TRUE))[[1]]
paste(result, collapse=" ")

[1] "I a see works not"
```

Comment: You need to escape the `\\s`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen explaining will help me learn new thing, if you don't mind, will you explain a bit about your first comment ?

Comment: @CodeManiac I edited your answer to make it work in R.  Not sure which one of our answers would perform better.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ohh i see you meant to make specific to `R`, anyways thanks for edit, i don't have any knowledge of `R` as i am very new to industry, but i know that regex is somewhat cross-platform which is supported by most of languages with some limitations, so i added this answer

Comment: OK, but for future reference, if the question is tagged with a specific programming language, then the OP and also anyone who might be reading it in the future is probably expecting a working solution in that actual language.  But, your answer is valid, as [you can see in this demo](https://rextester.com/VPANL19454).

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of more approaches

First approach:

```
str_split(test.string, " ", n=Inf) %>%  # spliting the line into words
unlist %>% 
.[!str_detect(., "\\W|\r")] %>%         # detect words without punctuation or \r
paste(.,collapse=" ")                   # collapse the words to get the line
```

Second approach:

```
str_extract_all(test.string, "^\\w+|\\s\\w+\\s|\\w+$") %>% 
unlist %>% 
trimws() %>% 
paste(., collapse=" ")
```

- `^\\w+` - words having only [a-zA-Z0-9_] and also is start of the string
- `\\s\\w+\\s` - words with [a-zA-Z0-9_] and having space before and after the word
- `\\w+$` - words having [a-zA-Z0-9_] and also is the end of the string